# AngularJS: stop everything and redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

In AngularJS, is there any way to stop the current script (even during a digest), and simply redirect to another page ?

Here is a very simple example of what I would like to do (note: in coffee script):
At the launch of a controller:

```
unless $routeParams.plan
    $errorManager.display("Missing plan parameter.") 
    $location.path('/')
```

My problem is that since angular is in a digest during this load, it ends the digest before the path change is applied.
Therefore, I got multiple other errors that pollutes the user...

Comment: Throwing an exception will halt execution and go to an errorHandler if you have one defined

Comment: Personally I wouldn't handle this with angular, I'd handle this at the server level with a 400 Bad Syntax error. If someone is giving you a bad url they should get an error code, not a 200 with an error on the page and a redirect.